# Astar pathinding maxSpeed value private. i cant change it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

So i am making a game and using a* pathfinding. I want to change the maxSpeed value but its private and if i change it to public unity gives me the error

***"Assets/AstarPathfindingProject/Core/AI/AIPath.cs(230,25): error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item"***

can somebody help me with that.

the line for that:

`float IAstarAI.maxSpeed { get { return maxSpeed; } set { maxSpeed = value; } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AIPath** derives from **AIBase** which already has a public **maxSpeed** value.

If you look closely at **IAstarAI.maxSpeed** it gets/sets the **maxSpeed** from **AIBase**.

You should be able to simply write:

```
myAi.maxSpeed = 1f;
```

Comment: thanks i just needed to add `public AIBase aibase` at the top and then i wrote `aibase.maxSpeed += 10;` Thx